# How to understand the multipole expansion?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics, multipole-expansion

How to understand the multipole expansion? I just can't understand the description given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion). It seems on Wikipedia that the formula is about a function only with angle variable, but I think to describe the distribution of matter or potential, radial distance is also needed. Am I having a wrong concept? And how to calculate the multipole expansion of a given charge distribution or mass distribution?

Comment: Hi wsjyhaozi, I edited the question. Please edit if that was not what you meant.

Comment: @Qmechanic That is exactly what I meant. Thank you for correction!

Comment: The Wikipedia page you linked actually shows the expansion for the electric potential, including the $r$-dependence

Comment: @fqq Thanks a lot. I just omitted that... Additionally, what is the physical meaning of the quadrupole term and even higher term?

Comment: What textbooks have you looked at that cover the subject?

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm now working hard on gravitational wave, and the lowest radiation form of GW is quadrupole radiation. But I can't find a book to help me get the expansion of any given distribution. All the examples given in books are the most simple cases such as electric dipole or magnetic dipole. Maybe I'm too stupid to understand the general form of multipole expansion'

Comment: @wsjyhaozi just my two cents, but I think this might be too broad of a question, as chapters are devoted to the subject. It might be worth a request for resources instead of this post (assuming this hasn't been asked previously).

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks for your advice. I'm just trying to understand why are we doing this? What's the motivation of multipole expansion. You know it's much more abstract compared with Taylor expansion.